# Segmentation fault on linux (g++) but not on Mac OS.?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, c++11, segmentation-fault

First of all I would like to apologize for my large code. I tried to keep it structured, but I am still new to programming in C++.

I created a C++ algorithm on OSX and it worked just fine. I need to run this program on Linux however. Compiling on Linux gave no errors, however when I run the program it gives the following error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am a newbie in debugging code and have tried to debug it with **gdb**, but I don't know how I should continue. The information **gdb** gives is the following:

```
c2f_function(new_candidates2, old_candidates, feature_list);
(gdb) 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000403dc5 in c2f_function (new_candidates=std::list = {...}, old_candidates=std::list = {...}, 
    feature_list=empty std::list) at /home/martin/emc/group4/src/c2f_function.cpp:36
36          norm = iter_old->x -iter_new->x;
```

I have added the code below, it consists of a main file **c2f.cpp**, a header file **c2f.hpp** and an additional file where I store functions **c2f_functions.cpp**.

The error seems to happen when I pass 3 *lists* by reference to a function called *c2f_functions*. this function is within the **c2f_functions.cpp** script.

My questions are,

1. how can I solve this?
2. why does it work well under OSX but not under Linux?

Many thnaks!

**MAIN FILE c2f.cpp:**

```
#include "c2f.hpp"
#include "c2f_function.cpp"


int main()
{
  // define variables
  double x, y;

  // create old candidates list
  list<Candidate> old_candidates;

  // create new candidates list
  list<Candidate> new_candidates1;
  list<Candidate> new_candidates2;
  list<Candidate> new_candidates3;

  // create new features list
  list<Candidate> feature_list;

  //=============================================================================//
  // LOAD FIRST DATA SET
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    ifstream file1_("newcandidates_it0.txt");
    if (file1_.is_open())
    {
      cout << "Reading file...1 " << endl;
      while( file1_ >> x >> y)
      {
        // cout << x << "," << y << endl;
        new_candidates1.push_back(Candidate(x , y));

      }
      file1_.close();
    }
    else {cout << "file is not open";}
  //=============================================================================//

  c2f_function(new_candidates1, old_candidates, feature_list);


  //=============================================================================//
  // LOAD SECOND DATA SET
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

  ifstream file2_("newcandidates_it1.txt");
    if (file2_.is_open())
    {
      cout << "Reading file...2 " << endl;
      while( file2_ >> x >> y)
      {
        // cout << x << "," << y << endl;
        new_candidates2.push_back(Candidate(x , y));

      }
      file2_.close();
    }
    else {cout << "file is not open";}
  //=============================================================================//

  c2f_function(new_candidates2, old_candidates, feature_list);
```

**HEADER FILE c2f.hpp**

```
# include <iostream>
# include <stdlib.h> 
# include <string>
# include <math.h>
# include <Eigen/Dense>
# include <cstdio>
# include <cstdlib>
# include <list>
# include <fstream>
# include <algorithm>
// # include <cstdarg>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

// correspondence margin: new point must lie w/i 10cm from old point
# define CORR_MARGIN    0.1
# define PERSIST_UB     3
# define PERSIST_LB     -PERSIST_UB

class Candidate
{
public:
    int id;
    double x;
    double y;
    int persistency = 0;
    int pflag = 0; // persistency flag

    Candidate ( double xNew, double yNew ): x(xNew), y(yNew){}

    void increasePersistency() 
    { 
        if (persistency < PERSIST_UB) // bound persistency from above
            persistency++; 
    }
    void decreasePersistency() 
    { 
        if (persistency > PERSIST_LB) // bound persistency from below
            persistency--; 
    }
    // bool operator< (const Candidate& right) const { return id < right.id; }

};

bool ascendingId ( Candidate a, Candidate b)
{
    return a.id < b.id;
}

bool descendingId ( Candidate a, Candidate b)
{
    return a.id > b.id;
}

bool ascendingPersistency ( Candidate a, Candidate b)
{
    return a.persistency < b.persistency;
}

bool descendingPersistency ( Candidate a, Candidate b)
{
    return a.persistency > b.persistency;
}

bool ascendingPflag ( Candidate a, Candidate b)
{
    return a.pflag < b.pflag;
}

bool descendingPflag ( Candidate a, Candidate b)
{
    return a.pflag > b.pflag;
}

bool sameId_Feature (Feature first, Feature second)
{ return first.id == second.id; }

bool samePflag (Candidate first, Candidate second)
{ return first.persistency == second.persistency; }


bool finder (Candidate first, Candidate second)
{return first.id == second.id;}


bool not_persistent (Candidate &a) 
{ return (a.persistency==PERSIST_LB); }
```

**Functions File c2f_function.cpp**

```
void print_list(list<Candidate> &list2print)
{
  for (auto const &iter : list2print)
  {
    cout  << iter.x 
          << "," << iter.y 
          << " with id " 
          << iter.id
          << " and persistency "
          << iter.persistency
          << endl;
  }
}


void c2f_function(list<Candidate> &new_candidates, list<Candidate> &old_candidates, list<Candidate> &feature_list)
{

  double norm;

  //=============================================================================//
  // CHECK FOR CORRESPONDENCE
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

  // Check if old candidates exist (initialization purposes)
  if (old_candidates.empty() == 0) // old candidates exist
  {
    // Check Correspondence
    for (auto iter_old = old_candidates.begin(); iter_old != old_candidates.end(); iter_old++)
    {
      // int persistency_upd_flag = 0;
      for (auto iter_new = new_candidates.begin(); iter_new != new_candidates.end(); iter_new++)
      {
        // compute the norm between old_candidates and new_candidates
        // norm = sqrt( pow(iter_old->x - iter_new->x, 2.0) + pow(iter_old->y - iter_new->y, 2.0));
        norm = iter_old->x -iter_new->x;
        if (norm <= CORR_MARGIN)
        {
          // Update position of old entry and increase persistency
          iter_old -> x = iter_new->x;
          iter_old -> y = iter_new->y;
          iter_old -> increasePersistency();
          // flag an update;
          iter_old -> pflag = 1;

          // remove list entry that has been coupled
          new_candidates.erase(iter_new);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    back_insert_iterator<list<Candidate>>  it(old_candidates);

    for (auto const &iter : new_candidates)
    {
      it = iter;
    }
    int counter=1;
    for (auto iter = old_candidates.begin(); iter!= old_candidates.end(); iter++)
    {
      iter -> id = counter;

      ++counter;
    }
    cout << "initializing data set" << endl;
    cout << endl << "====================================================" << endl;
    return;
  }
  //=============================================================================//


  //=============================================================================//
  // DECREASE PERSISTENCY FOR NON-VIEWED CANDIDATES
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

  // remove persistency to non-associated candidates
  old_candidates.sort(ascendingPflag);
  for (auto iter = old_candidates.begin(); iter!= old_candidates.end(); iter++)
  {
    if ( iter -> pflag == 0 )
    {
      iter -> decreasePersistency();

      find_if (feature_list.begin(), feature_list.end(),
      [iter] (Candidate &item)
      {
        if (item.id == iter->id)
        {
          item.persistency = iter->persistency;
          return true;
        }
        else return false;
      }
      );
    }
    // reset pflags
    iter -> pflag = 0; 
  }
  //=============================================================================//


  //=============================================================================//
  // ADD id TO REMAINING new_candidates LIST
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

  // get new id
  old_candidates.sort(descendingId);
  int new_id = old_candidates.begin() -> id + 1;

  // add id to added items to old_candidates
  for (auto iter = new_candidates.begin(); iter!= new_candidates.end(); iter++)
  {
    iter -> id = new_id;
    new_id++;
  }
  //=============================================================================//

  //=============================================================================//
  // MERGE REMAINING new_candidates WITH old_candidates LIST
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------//
  old_candidates.splice(old_candidates.end(), new_candidates);
  //=============================================================================//


  //=============================================================================//
  // ADD TO feature_list
  // REMOVE FROM feature_list
  // REMOVE FROM old_list
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

 // removing from old_candidates when persistency @ lower bound
  old_candidates.sort(ascendingPersistency);

  for (auto const &iter_old : old_candidates)
  {

    if (iter_old.persistency == PERSIST_LB)
    {
      old_candidates.pop_front();
    }
    else
      {break;}
  }

 // removing from feature_list when persistency @ lower bound
  feature_list.sort(ascendingPersistency);

  for (auto const &iter_feat : feature_list)
  {
    if (iter_feat.persistency == PERSIST_LB)
    {
      feature_list.pop_front();
    }
    else
      {break;}
  }


  // sorting
  old_candidates.sort(descendingPersistency);

  // adding
  back_insert_iterator<list<Candidate>>  it(feature_list);

  // define counter
  int counter;

  for (auto const &iter_old : old_candidates)
  {
    counter =0;
    if (iter_old.persistency == PERSIST_UB)
    {
      if (feature_list.size()>0)
      {
        for (auto iter_feat = feature_list.begin(); iter_feat != feature_list.end(); iter_feat++)
        {
          if (iter_feat->id == iter_old.id)
          {
            iter_feat->x = iter_old.x;
            iter_feat->y = iter_old.y; 
            iter_feat->persistency = iter_old.persistency;
            counter  = 0;
            break;          
          }
          else
          {
            counter++;
          }
        }
        if (counter >0)
        {
          it = iter_old;
        }

      }
      else
        it = iter_old;
    }
    else
    {
      break;
    }

  }

  //=============================================================================//


  //=============================================================================//
  // DISPLAY FEATURE LIST
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------//
  if (feature_list.size() > 0)
  {
    feature_list.sort(ascendingId);
    cout << "Feature members" << endl;
    print_list(feature_list);
    cout << endl << "====================================================" << endl;
  }
  else
    cout << endl << "====================================================" << endl;
  //=============================================================================//

}

  //*****************************************************************************//
  //*****************************************************************************//
```

Comment: Typical symptopm of undefined behavior.

Comment: First thing to do is type`bt` in gdb to get a backtrace so you can see how you arrived at the location with the error. Second thing to do is learn more about gdb ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I suspect the problem is that you erase an iterator and, next, you use (increment) it.

The following is the crucial part

```
  for (auto iter_new = new_candidates.begin(); iter_new != new_candidates.end(); iter_new++)
  {
    norm = iter_old->x -iter_new->x;
    if (norm <= CORR_MARGIN)
    {
      // [...]
      new_candidates.erase(iter_new);
    }
  }
```

When you `erase(iter_new)`, `iter_new` become an iterator pointing to an invalid object; incrementing it (`iter_new++`) give you (if I'm not wrong) an undefined value and the following `iter_new->x` can segmentation fault your program.

I suppose that a solution can be the use of the postfix increment calling `erase()` so that `erase()` call a copy of `iter_new` and `iter_new` is incremented to a valid iterator before the call to `erase()`; something like

```
  auto = new_candidates.begin();
  while ( iter_new != new_candidates.end() )
  {
    norm = iter_old->x -iter_new->x;
    if (norm <= CORR_MARGIN)
    {
      // [...]
      new_candidates.erase( iter_new++ );
    }
    else
      ++iter_new;
  }
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped to repair my code. The problem indeed resided in deleting `iter_new`. As I only had to delete one item, what I eventually did was add a `break` after deleting `iter_new`. This way when the item is deleted the 2nd for loop (the one I break) starts over again and the iterator starts over again and therefore the `iter_new` cannot point to an invalid object anymore. Thanks again very much for taking the effort to answer my question!

Answer (score 4):

SYSSEGV Segmentation Fault is caused by an attempt to access memory outside of the program's allowed area.  In this case, either iter_old or iter_new is not initialized or contains a value that does not correspond to the program's memory area.

It may crash on one computer system and not on another because 1) different systems can have different values in uninitialized variables and 2) different systems define the programs available memory differently.

In short, look for bad pointer values with SEGV errors, and know that bugs can appear in different ways on different systems.

Comment: The problem indeed resided in `iter_new`. As @max66 pointed out, when `iter_new` is deleted, it becomes an iterator pointing to an invalid object. I solved this by adding a `break` after deleting the item to step out of the for loop and reinitialize the iterator. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question.